# How to show rows horizontally instead of vertically?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2012

I am getting records like this:

```
Rev-- Status-- Remarks-- RemarksDate -- User
0     prepared  done     12/jul/2019    John
0     approved  done     12/jul/2019    Amy
0     Issued    done     13/jul/2019    Tom
1     REOPENED  done     14/jul/2019    John
1     Prepared  done     14/jul/2019    Ritz
```

but I am trying to display like this

```
Rev   PreparedBy APprovedBy IssuedBy REOPENEDBy  Date
0     John       Amy        Tom      John        onlyissuedate
1     John       Ritz       Marine   Riya            //
```

I am trying to achive this without changing the table structure but cannot.

Query:

```
        Select * from table
```

No need to include remarks in the 2nd format.

For prepared I am using `status# 0` and for `approve 1`, for `issue 3`, for `reopened 5`.

Answer (score 2):

A pivot query approach should work here:

```
SELECT
    rh.Rev,
    MAX(CASE WHEN rh.Status = 'prepared' THEN rh.RemarksByName END) AS PreparedBy,
    MAX(CASE WHEN rh.Status = 'approved' THEN rh.RemarksByName END) AS ApprovedBy,
    MAX(CASE WHEN rh.Status = 'Issued'   THEN rh.RemarksByName END) AS IssuedBy,
    MAX(CASE WHEN rh.Status = 'REOPENED' THEN rh.RemarksByName END) AS reopenedBy,
    MAX(CASE WHEN rh.Status = 'Issued'   THEN rh.RemarksDate END)   AS Date
FROM RemarksHisotry rh
INNER JOIN inspectionReport ir
    ON ir.InspectionReportID = rh.InspectionReportID
INNER JOIN Status s
    ON s.StatusID = rh.[Status]
WHERE
    ir.VelosiReportNo = @InspectionReportNo
GROUP BY
    rh.Rev
ORDER BY
    rh.Rev;
```

Answer (score 1):

This may help.

```
DECLARE @TempData TABLE(Rev VARCHAR(10),Status VARCHAR(50),Remarks VARCHAR(50),RemarksDate DATE,UserName VARCHAR(50))
INSERT INTO  @TempData VALUES
('0',     'Prepared',  'done',     '12/jul/2019',    'John'),
('0',     'Approved',  'done',     '12/jul/2019',    'Amy '),
('0',     'Issued  ',  'done',     '13/jul/2019',    'Tom '),
('0',     'Reopened',  'done',     '14/jul/2019',    'John'),
('1',     'Reopened',  'done',     '14/jul/2019',    'Marine'),
('1',     'Prepared',  'done',     '14/jul/2019',    'John'),
('1',     'Approved',  'done',     '12/jul/2019',    'Ritz '),
('1',     'Issued',    'done',     '14/jul/2019',    'John')

SELECT pvtValue.Rev
      ,pvtValue.Prepared PreparedBy
      ,pvtValue.Approved ApprovedBy
      ,pvtValue.Issued IssuedBy
      ,pvtValue.Reopened ReopenedBy
      ,t.RemarksDate IssueDate
FROM( 
     SELECT Rev,Status,UserName
     FROM  @TempData

     ) pvt
     PIVOT (MAX(UserName) FOR STATUS IN (Prepared,Approved,Issued, Reopened )
     ) pvtValue 
     LEFT JOIN @TempData t ON pvtValue.Issued = t.UserName AND pvtValue.Rev = t.Rev AND t.Status = 'Issued'
```

[image]

Comment: Yep, this is just the job for `PIVOT`.

Answer (score 0):

You can simply achieve that without having to `JOIN` any copies of the same table.
All you need is a way to convert each row value into a column, (we will use `CASE WHEN` for that), and we will combine that with the aggregate function `MAX` which will ignore `NULL` values we specify in the case above.

```
select 
    rev,
    max(case when status='prepared' then user        else null end) preparedBy,
    max(case when status='approved' then user        else null end) approvedBy,
    max(case when status='Issued'   then user        else null end) IssuedBy  ,
    max(case when status='REOPENED' then user        else null end) reopenedBy,
    max(case when status='Issued'   then remarksdate else null end) date
from
    table_name
group by
    rev
order by
    rev
```

Comment: @Stacky I edited my post, my previous post was accepted before I was done with it